# Solving $x^3-(2+2n)x^2-(4n+1)x+(2m^2-2n)=0$ for real $m$ and $n$

Tags: cubics

I do not know how to solve this cubic equation. The background of this problem is from lagrange multiplier. I use lagrange multuplier to find the distance from point(m,n) to parabola. and I stuck with this step.

$$
x^3 - (2+2n)x^2 - (4n+1)x + (2m^2 - 2n) = 0
$$
when $m$ and $n$ are real numbers.

How to solve it?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you seeking conditions where there is an integer root?

Comment: When $m=\pm1$ it factorises nicely as $(x+1)(x^2-(2n+3)x-2n+2)$.

Comment: The word constant is _vague_ when it comes to mathematics, is $m$ and $n$   real, rational, natural - numbers? etc.  Also as can be seen on [wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E3-%282%2B2n%29x%5E2-%284n%2B1%29x%2B%282m%5E2-2n%29%3D0) there are a lot of solutions, each depending on your choice of $m$ and $n$.

Comment: If you want to solve for $x$, consider using [Cardano's formula](https://brilliant.org/wiki/cardano-method/).

Comment: I'm sorry. I mean m and n are real numbers. Thank you for your advice, I edited it.

Comment: @Mathskid, if u want $x$ in terms of $m$ and $n$, there isn't a very neat expression, what is the background or context of this problem?

Comment: I do try to find the shortest distance from point(m,n) to the parabola by using lagrange multiplier. So I stuck with this step.